# Have I created a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

As the title reads, I am unsure if what I have created is a separate thread or not. I have used a Handler, and a Runnable and such, but I don't know what counts as a thread and what doesn't.

My code:

```
Handler hand = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set full-screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    // Initialize variables from popup window
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu,
            null, false));
    storeDismiss = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(
            R.id.menudismissid);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    goldCount = (long) prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);

    textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);
    textGoldCount.setText(goldCount + " Gold");
    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mechanical.ttf");
    textGoldCount.setTypeface(tf);
    textGoldCount.setTextSize(35);

    // Linking the variables
    minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
    storeClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storeimageid);

    spinningBars = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spinningbarsid);

    // Setting onClickListeners
    minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    storeClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Begin animation of bars
    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.spinningbarsanimation);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    spinningBars.startAnimation(rotation);

    hand.postDelayed(run, 1000);

    /*goldPerSecondMethod();*/


}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        longSwordPerSecond();
    }
};

public void longSwordPerSecond() {
    if (goldCount>1)
        goldCount += 0.1f;
        textGoldCount.setText(goldCount + " Gold");
        textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        hand.postDelayed(run, 1000);


}
```

I've also been told to use a HandlerThread or something, but there are virtually no concise tutorials around explaining how they work and how to create them.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have not. Handler is attached to the Looper of the current thread, in this case the UI thread. If you want to assign it to a different thread, you can use the following code:

```
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ThreadName");
    thread.start();

    hand = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
```

Where hand is your Handler object

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) Though I'm getting the syntax error "Syntax error on token "start", Identifier expected after this token" on .start(); , which I don't know how to fix. Also, what is a "Handler object"? I ask this as I'm getting the error "Syntax error on token "mHandler", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token". I'm quite new to coding, so a lot of the terminology such as "Handler object" I don't yet understand.

Comment: For the explanation of what this means, check these links: 
[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

[Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)
[HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)

For the syntax error, there might have been a problem while copy and paste, the logic and the code snippet is correct (I double-checked)

Comment: I can't see any links :(

Comment: Hit enter too early. Updated :)

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the links :) So just a last query; This "MyHandlerClass" in the code, does it refer to a class I have to surround the runnable in, or something else? I only ask because using the official android site to explain anything to myself is like learning Spanish by reading newspaper articles - I have no idea what any of it means :')

Comment: well, it can be a normal Handler class, as it also has a constructor which receives the Looper. Then you can assign it your runnables and it will run it on the thread you specified.

Comment: It works! Really well! Thanks friend :) Also, to anyone reading this later, make sure to put the guy's code in the onCreate() method. Also, "hand" refers to the Handler I created using "Handler hand = new Handler();"

Answer (score 1):

My code with functioning thread (I removed most of the other code specific to my app). Enjoy!

```
Handler hand = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ThreadName");
    thread.start();

    hand = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
    hand.postDelayed(run, 1000);

}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        longSwordPerSecond();
    }
};


public void longSwordPerSecond() {
    if (goldCount>1)
        goldCount += 0.1f;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                textGoldCount.setText(goldCount + " Gold");

            }
        });
        hand.postDelayed(run, 1000);


}
```

The "runonuithread" is used to update the UI. So the math is done in the thread, and the only bit the UI does is show the result. That way the UI is not locked up by the process!